# I have a pdf file with a field called first name. I'm trying to pre populate the field with c# code

Tags: c#, docusignapi

// Step 2. Call DocuSign to create the envelope
var docuSignClient = new DocuSignClient(basePath);
docuSignClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

```
        EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(docuSignClient);
        EnvelopeSummary results = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envelope);
        string envelopeId = results.EnvelopeId;

        // Step 2 end

        // Step 3 start
        // Step 3. create the recipient view, the Signing Ceremony
        RecipientViewRequest viewRequest = MakeRecipientViewRequest(signerEmail, signerName, returnUrl, signerClientId, pingUrl);

        // call the CreateRecipientView API
        ViewUrl results1 = envelopesApi.CreateRecipientView(accountId, envelopeId, viewRequest);

        // Step 3 end

        // Step 4 start
        // Step 4. Redirect the user to the Signing Ceremony
        // Don't use an iFrame!
        // State can be stored/recovered using the framework's session or a
        // query parameter on the returnUrl (see the makeRecipientViewRequest method)
        string redirectUrl = results1.Url;

        // returning both the envelopeId as well as the url to be used for embedded signing
        return (envelopeId, redirectUrl);

        // Step 4 end
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We have code to show you how to do this here - https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp/blob/master/launcher-csharp/eSignature/Examples/SetEnvelopeTabValue.cs

The code inside the `CreateEnvelope()` method you have above has to have this:

```
        Text textLegal = new Text
        {
            AnchorString = "/legal/",
            AnchorUnits = "pixels",
            AnchorYOffset = "-9",
            AnchorXOffset = "5",
            Font = "helvetica",
            FontSize = "size11",
            Bold = "true",
            Value = signerName,
            Locked = "false",
            TabId = "legal_name",
            TabLabel = "Legal name",
        };


        // Create the envelope definition
        EnvelopeDefinition envelopeAttributes = new EnvelopeDefinition()
        {
            EnvelopeIdStamping = "true",
            EmailSubject = "Please Sign",
            EmailBlurb = "Sample text for email body",
            Status = "Sent",
            Recipients = recipients,
            CustomFields = cf,
            Documents = new List<Document> { doc1 },
        };

        // Call the eSignature REST API
        EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(docuSignClient);
        EnvelopeSummary results = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envelopeAttributes);
        string envelopeId = results.EnvelopeId;
```